# how to get view references in SAPUI5?

Tags: javascript, xml, sapui5

Let's say I have my routes defined in my manifest.json like this

```
rootView: "sap.ui.core.sample.TargetsStandalone.targetsApp.view.App",
        routing: {
            config: {
                targetsClass: "sap.m.routing.Targets",
                viewPath: "sap.ui.core.sample.TargetsStandalone.targetsApp.view",
                controlId: "rootControl",
                controlAggregation: "pages",
                viewType: "XML"
            },
            targets: {
                page1: {
                    viewName: "View1",
                    viewLevel: 0
                },
                page2: {
                    viewName: "View2",
                    viewLevel: 1
                }
            }
        }
```

Is there a way to retrieve the view references from the component(getOwnerComponent). What I want to do is, on the first controller I want to get a reference of label on "View2". It seems like there is no reference to the second view until I navigate to it. Is there a way to get the a reference to another view and its elements before I navigate to it?

Comment: It does not work like this, and you can't have a reference to a view before it gets instantiated.

Comment: I forgot I can use models since I have them on my manifest.json. I decided to add a model to it. That way I can set the model from anywhere since they are global.

Comment: yes, working with models is the preferable way

Answer (score 0):

When you navigate to a view, the runtime instantiate it. Before that, there is no view. You can even see in the network trace how the XML file of certain view is downloaded once you navigate to it for the first time, but not before.